# Juju Zookeeper & Provisioning Agent Not Deployed

Tags: juju

I am using juju with the openstack provider, i expected that when i bootstrap that zookeeper and provisioning agent would get deployed on the bootstrap vm in openstack.
This dose not seem to be the case. the bootstrap vm gets deployed but it seems that nothing  gets deployed to the VM. See logs below, I may be missing something, also how is it possible to log on the bootstrap vm. Could I manual deploy, if so what do I need to do.

---

### Juju Bootstrap commend

```
root@cinder01:/home/cinder# juju -v bootstrap
2012-10-12 03:21:20,976 DEBUG Initializing juju bootstrap runtime
2012-10-12 03:21:20,982 WARNING Verification of xxxxS certificates is disabled for this environment.
Set 'ssl-hostname-verification' to ensure secure communication.
2012-10-12 03:21:20,982 DEBUG openstack: using auth-mode 'userpass' with xxxx:xxxxxx.10:35357/v2.0/
2012-10-12 03:21:21,064 DEBUG openstack: authenticated til u'2012-10-13T08:21:13Z'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,064 DEBUG openstack: GET 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,091 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"flavors": [{"id": "3", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/3", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/3", "rel": "bookmark"}], "name": "m1.medium"}, {"id": "4", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/4", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/4", "rel": "bookmark"}], "name": "m1.large"}, {"id": "1", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/1", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}], "name": "m1.tiny"}, {"id": "5", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/5", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/5", "rel": "bookmark"}], "name": "m1.xlarge"}, {"id": "2", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/2", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/2", "rel": "bookmark"}], "name": "m1.small"}]}'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,091 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'openstack' (origin: ppa type: openstack)...
2012-10-12 03:21:21,091 DEBUG access object-store @ xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/provider-state
2012-10-12 03:21:21,092 DEBUG openstack: GET 'xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/provider-state'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,165 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{}\n'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,165 DEBUG Verifying writable storage
2012-10-12 03:21:21,165 DEBUG access object-store @ xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/bootstrap-verify
2012-10-12 03:21:21,166 DEBUG openstack: PUT 'xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/bootstrap-verify'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,251 DEBUG openstack: 201 '201 Created\n\n\n\n   '
2012-10-12 03:21:21,251 DEBUG Launching juju bootstrap instance.
2012-10-12 03:21:21,271 DEBUG access object-store @ xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/juju_master_id
2012-10-12 03:21:21,273 DEBUG access compute @ xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/os-security-groups
2012-10-12 03:21:21,273 DEBUG openstack: GET 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/os-security-groups'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,321 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"security_groups": [{"rules": [{"from_port": -1, "group": {}, "ip_protocol": "icmp", "to_port": -1, "parent_group_id": 1, "ip_range": {"cidr": "0.0.0.0/0"}, "id": 7}, {"from_port": 22, "group": {}, "ip_protocol": "tcp", "to_port": 22, "parent_group_id": 1, "ip_range": {"cidr": "0.0.0.0/0"}, "id": 38}], "tenant_id": "d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d", "id": 1, "name": "default", "description": "default"}]}'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,322 DEBUG Creating juju security group juju-openstack
2012-10-12 03:21:21,322 DEBUG openstack: POST 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/os-security-groups'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,401 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"security_group": {"rules": [], "tenant_id": "d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d", "id": 48, "name": "juju-openstack", "description": "juju group for openstack"}}'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,401 DEBUG openstack: POST 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/os-security-group-rules'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,504 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"security_group_rule": {"from_port": 22, "group": {}, "ip_protocol": "tcp", "to_port": 22, "parent_group_id": 48, "ip_range": {"cidr": "0.0.0.0/0"}, "id": 54}}'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,504 DEBUG openstack: POST 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/os-security-group-rules'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,647 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"security_group_rule": {"from_port": 1, "group": {"tenant_id": "d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d", "name": "juju-openstack"}, "ip_protocol": "tcp", "to_port": 65535, "parent_group_id": 48, "ip_range": {}, "id": 55}}'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,647 DEBUG openstack: POST 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/os-security-group-rules'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,791 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"security_group_rule": {"from_port": 1, "group": {"tenant_id": "d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d", "name": "juju-openstack"}, "ip_protocol": "udp", "to_port": 65535, "parent_group_id": 48, "ip_range": {}, "id": 56}}'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,792 DEBUG Creating machine security group juju-openstack-0
2012-10-12 03:21:21,792 DEBUG openstack: POST 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/os-security-groups'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,871 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"security_group": {"rules": [], "tenant_id": "d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d", "id": 49, "name": "juju-openstack-0", "description": "juju group for openstack machine 0"}}'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,871 DEBUG access compute @ xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/detail
2012-10-12 03:21:21,871 DEBUG openstack: GET 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/detail'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,906 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"flavors": [{"vcpus": 2, "disk": 10, "name": "m1.medium", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/3", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/3", "rel": "bookmark"}], "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral": 40, "ram": 4096, "id": "3", "swap": ""}, {"vcpus": 4, "disk": 10, "name": "m1.large", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/4", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/4", "rel": "bookmark"}], "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral": 80, "ram": 8192, "id": "4", "swap": ""}, {"vcpus": 1, "disk": 0, "name": "m1.tiny", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/1", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}], "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral": 0, "ram": 512, "id": "1", "swap": ""}, {"vcpus": 8, "disk": 10, "name": "m1.xlarge", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/5", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/5", "rel": "bookmark"}], "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral": 160, "ram": 16384, "id": "5", "swap": ""}, {"vcpus": 1, "disk": 10, "name": "m1.small", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/2", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/2", "rel": "bookmark"}], "rxtx_factor": 1.0, "OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral": 20, "ram": 2048, "id": "2", "swap": ""}]}'
2012-10-12 03:21:21,907 DEBUG access compute @ xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers
2012-10-12 03:21:21,907 DEBUG openstack: POST 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers'
2012-10-12 03:21:22,284 DEBUG openstack: 202 '{"server": {"OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL", "id": "a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023", "rel": "bookmark"}], "adminPass": "SuFp48cZzdo4"}}'
2012-10-12 03:21:22,284 DEBUG access object-store @ xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/juju_master_id
2012-10-12 03:21:22,285 DEBUG openstack: PUT 'xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/juju_master_id'
2012-10-12 03:21:22,375 DEBUG openstack: 201 '201 Created\n\n\n\n   '
2012-10-12 03:21:27,379 DEBUG Waited for 5 seconds for networking on server u'a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023'
2012-10-12 03:21:27,380 DEBUG access compute @ xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023
2012-10-12 03:21:27,380 DEBUG openstack: GET 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023'
2012-10-12 03:21:27,556 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"server": {"OS-EXT-STS:task_state": "networking", "addresses": {"private": [{"version": 4, "addr": "10.0.0.8"}]}, "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023", "rel": "bookmark"}], "image": {"id": "5bf60467-0136-4471-9818-e13ade75a0a1", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/images/5bf60467-0136-4471-9818-e13ade75a0a1", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "building", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name": "instance-00000060", "flavor": {"id": "1", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "id": "a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023", "user_id": "01610f73d0fb4922aefff09f2627e50c", "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL", "accessIPv4": "", "accessIPv6": "", "progress": 0, "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 0, "config_drive": "", "status": "BUILD", "updated": "2012-10-12T08:21:23Z", "hostId": "1cdb25708fb8e464d83a69fe4a024dcd5a80baf24a82ec28f9d9f866", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "nova01", "key_name": "", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname": null, "name": "juju openstack instance 0", "created": "2012-10-12T08:21:22Z", "tenant_id": "d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d", "metadata": {}}}'
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2012-10-12 03:21:27,557 DEBUG access compute @ xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/os-floating-ips
2012-10-12 03:21:27,557 DEBUG openstack: GET 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/os-floating-ips'
2012-10-12 03:21:27,815 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"floating_ips": [{"instance_id": "a0e0df11-91c0-4801-95b3-62d910d729e9", "ip": "xxxx.35", "fixed_ip": "10.0.0.5", "id": 447, "pool": "nova"}, {"instance_id": "b84f1a42-7192-415e-8650-ebb1aa56e97f", "ip": "xxxx.36", "fixed_ip": "10.0.0.6", "id": 448, "pool": "nova"}, {"instance_id": null, "ip": "xxxx.37", "fixed_ip": null, "id": 449, "pool": "nova"}, {"instance_id": null, "ip": "xxxx.38", "fixed_ip": null, "id": 450, "pool": "nova"}, {"instance_id": null, "ip": "xxxx.39", "fixed_ip": null, "id": 451, "pool": "nova"}, {"instance_id": null, "ip": "xxxx.40", "fixed_ip": null, "id": 452, "pool": "nova"}, {"instance_id": null, "ip": "xxxx.41", "fixed_ip": null, "id": 453, "pool": "nova"}]}'
2012-10-12 03:21:27,815 DEBUG access compute @ xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023/action
2012-10-12 03:21:27,816 DEBUG openstack: POST 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023/action'
2012-10-12 03:21:28,356 DEBUG openstack: 202 ''
2012-10-12 03:21:28,356 DEBUG access object-store @ xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/provider-state
2012-10-12 03:21:28,357 DEBUG openstack: PUT 'xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/provider-state'
2012-10-12 03:21:28,446 DEBUG openstack: 201 '201 Created\n\n\n\n   '
2012-10-12 03:21:28,446 INFO 'bootstrap' command finished successfully
```

---

### Juju Status Command

```
root@cinder01:/home/cinder# juju -v status
2012-10-12 03:23:28,314 DEBUG Initializing juju status runtime
2012-10-12 03:23:28,320 WARNING Verification of xxxxS certificates is disabled for this environment.
Set 'ssl-hostname-verification' to ensure secure communication.
2012-10-12 03:23:28,320 DEBUG openstack: using auth-mode 'userpass' with xxxx:xxxxxx.10:35357/v2.0/
2012-10-12 03:23:28,320 INFO Connecting to environment...
2012-10-12 03:23:28,403 DEBUG openstack: authenticated til u'2012-10-13T08:23:20Z'
2012-10-12 03:23:28,403 DEBUG access object-store @ xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/provider-state
2012-10-12 03:23:28,403 DEBUG openstack: GET 'xxxx:xx10.49.113.11:8080/v1/AUTH_d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/juju-hpc-az1-cb/provider-state'
2012-10-12 03:23:35,480 DEBUG openstack: 200 'zookeeper-instances: [a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023]\n'
2012-10-12 03:23:35,480 DEBUG access compute @ xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023
2012-10-12 03:23:35,480 DEBUG openstack: GET 'xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023'
2012-10-12 03:23:35,662 DEBUG openstack: 200 '{"server": {"OS-EXT-STS:task_state": null, "addresses": {"private": [{"version": 4, "addr": "10.0.0.8"}, {"version": 4, "addr": "xxxx.37"}]}, "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/v1.1/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023", "rel": "self"}, {"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/servers/a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023", "rel": "bookmark"}], "image": {"id": "5bf60467-0136-4471-9818-e13ade75a0a1", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/images/5bf60467-0136-4471-9818-e13ade75a0a1", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "active", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name": "instance-00000060", "flavor": {"id": "1", "links": [{"href": "xxxx:xxxxxx.15:8774/d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d/flavors/1", "rel": "bookmark"}]}, "id": "a598b402-8678-4447-baeb-59255409a023", "user_id": "01610f73d0fb4922aefff09f2627e50c", "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL", "accessIPv4": "", "accessIPv6": "", "progress": 0, "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 1, "config_drive": "", "status": "ACTIVE", "updated": "2012-10-12T08:21:40Z", "hostId": "1cdb25708fb8e464d83a69fe4a024dcd5a80baf24a82ec28f9d9f866", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "nova01", "key_name": "", "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname": null, "name": "juju openstack instance 0", "created": "2012-10-12T08:21:22Z", "tenant_id": "d5f52673953f49e595279e89ddde979d", "metadata": {}}}'
2012-10-12 03:23:35,663 DEBUG Connecting to environment using xxxx.37...
2012-10-12 03:23:35,663 DEBUG Spawning SSH process with remote_user="ubuntu" remote_host="xxxx.37" remote_port="2181" local_port="45859".
2012-10-12 03:23:36,173:4355(0x7fd581973700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@658: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.3.5
2012-10-12 03:23:36,173:4355(0x7fd581973700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@662: Client environment:host.name=cinder01
2012-10-12 03:23:36,174:4355(0x7fd581973700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@669: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2012-10-12 03:23:36,174:4355(0x7fd581973700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@670: Client environment:os.arch=3.2.0-23-generic
2012-10-12 03:23:36,174:4355(0x7fd581973700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@671: Client environment:os.version=#36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012
2012-10-12 03:23:36,174:4355(0x7fd581973700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@679: Client environment:user.name=cinder
2012-10-12 03:23:36,174:4355(0x7fd581973700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@687: Client environment:user.home=/root
2012-10-12 03:23:36,175:4355(0x7fd581973700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@699: Client environment:user.dir=/home/cinder
2012-10-12 03:23:36,175:4355(0x7fd581973700):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@727: Initiating client connection, host=localhost:45859 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=0x7fd57f9146b0 sessionId=0 sessionPasswd=<null> context=0x2c1dab0 flags=0
2012-10-12 03:23:36,175:4355(0x7fd577fff700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:45859] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-10-12 03:23:39,512:4355(0x7fd577fff700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:45859] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
2012-10-12 03:23:42,848:4355(0x7fd577fff700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1579: Socket [127.0.0.1:45859] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
^Croot@cinder01:/home/cinder#
```